# Writing overlaps function

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I want to write a polymorphic function that inputs two lists and tells me whether these two lists contain a common element. My attempt at writing this function is as follows:

```
overlaps :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
overlaps x:xs y:ys  
   | x `is_element_of` ys = True
   | otherwise = False
```

where

```
is_element_of :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
is_element_of e list = case list of
[] -> False
x: xs -> e == x || e `is_element_of` xs
```

However this isn't working... Is it possible to pattern match against two lists? Is this a possible way of writing this function?

Comment: Your pattern match doesn't work because all pattern matches in function arguments have to be in parentheses. Also, if you pattern match on the second list like this, you're throwing away its first element which you probably don't want.

Comment: ```overlaps xs = any (`elem` xs)```

Comment: Are the lists ordered? Because then you can boost performance.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `is_elem_of` already exists in the `Data.List` package as `elem`. Using that, `overlaps` is easy to write.

```
overlaps []     _  = False
overlaps (x:xs) ys = x `elem` ys || overlaps xs ys
```

As you can tell, it is possible to pattern match on lists. If you want to write the function *without* pattern matching on lists, you can use the `foldr` function.

```
overlaps xs ys = foldr (\x acc -> x `elem` ys || acc) False xs
```

Comment: Above `foldl` lacks an argument. Further, I'd prefer `foldr` here since `foldl` always scans the whole `xs` and there's no need to do that.

Comment: @chi, thank you for pointing out the error. It was my understanding that `foldr` was strict in both arguments to its function, while `foldl` was lazy. Is that incorrect? If not, wouldn't that mean that *`foldr`* would scan the entire list while *`foldl`* would short circuit as soon as `||` hit a `True` value?

Comment: @Kwarrtz, `foldr` is lazier than `foldl`. In fact you can implement `foldl` using `foldr` (GHC does this!) but not the other way around.

Comment: `foldr (||) undefined (True : undefined)` gives True

Comment: @dfuer Ah, my mistake then. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want something like this (untested):

```
overlaps :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
overlaps [] _        = False
overlaps _ []        = False
overlaps (x:xs) list = x `myelem` list || overlaps xs list

myelem :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
myelem _ []     = False
myelem x (y:ys) = x == y || myelem x ys
```

AFAIK using the pattern matching appropach is more idiomatic.